# Which is better? Starting to Allegro or OpenGL

Tags: opengl, directx, allegro

I want you to help me for a decision problem.

I am a newbie video game programmer. I can develop Flash, Unity, Android games, and I know a little CryEngine. Also, I want to develop 3D video games in the future.

So, I decided to learn a video game library that I can work with C/C++. But should I learn Allegro or OpenGL or a different library? Or should I directly start to learn DirectX programming? Learning Allegro programming is useful (a good basis) or just a waste of time?

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for this site.

Answer (score 6):

> But should I learn Allegro or OpenGL or a different library?

First and foremost: *OpenGL is not a library!* The 'L' of it once meant library, but it's better to backronym it as "layer", because that's what OpenGL really is these days: A layer between your program and the graphics hardware.

OpenGL is not a game engine, it's not a game graphics library. *OpenGL is a low level drawing API.* You can use it to draw points, lines and triangles in fancy ways. But there's no scene, no objects and such in OpenGL. All this must be implemented by the game engine. Writing a game engine is very hard work. If you really want to go for this, I suggest you look at the source code of Doom3, which has been released a year ago.

Answer (score 3):

Allegro has almost nothing to do with OpenGL.

Allegro is a basic framework for simple game development providing rudimentary 2D graphic primitives, user input, text, sound, timers, etc... You can use OpenGL under Allegro, but there is no tight and specialized integration.

OpenGL is a low level API, specialized for graphics.

If you already know Unity and CryEngine, stick to them. It would be a tremendous difficulty to implement even a fraction of their features using OpenGL on your own. That doesn't mean you shouldn't learn some OpenGL, even for the sake of curiosity and understanding how stuff works on the low level.

DirectX is platform limited, and while it is true the majority of gaming platforms do support DX, ARM mobile platforms are on the rise, and DirectX doesn't run on them. OpenGL can match pretty much everything D3D has to offer, and it is more portable, so it is the API that is more worth investing in, unless you are centered on Windows games exclusively. Then it would make sense to learn D3D, which is a little easier to use.

Many game engines, including Unity, will abstract away from the graphics API and use the best what the target platform provides.

Also, keep in mind that OpenGL is not available on Windows 8 in "metro" mode, so you will either have to use D3D if you want advanced graphics under metro mode, or use ANGLE and stick to more basic subset of OpenGL that is emulated with ANGLE on top of D3D.

Comment: What do you mean by your comments about Allegro? Version 5 is built directly on OpenGL. It is indeed meant for 2D games, but it can also be used as a cross platform windowing and input library for any type of application. It is not an engine, and really isn't comparable to some of the other things mentioned.

Comment: Never said Allegro is an engine. Which part of my answer you find incorrect?

Comment: Nothing really, but some people might misunderstand what you mean by "it has almost nothing to do with OpenGL". On one hand, yes, you can use Allegro without knowing any OpenGL, but it helps to understand how it uses OpenGL so that you can use it more efficiently. And if you make use of OpenGL in conjunction with Allegro, you can do more advanced things.